# Is there any way to hide ipfs addresses without using ipns?

Tags: ipfs

For practical purposes, it is important that files can be deleted, so the ipfs address cannot be used as is.
However, ipns is currently very slow.
Is there any way to hide the ipfs address without using ipns?

Comment: Please say what you've tried, and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

On https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/ipns/ is step by step information how using ipns.

```
$ipfs name resolve [ipns key]
```

You get ipfs directly

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33744905)

Comment: In addition to the above comment, can you clarify how your answer is specifically an answer to the question?

Comment: >is specifically an answer to the question? " yes, You must type ipfs program name etc. this is exactly string what You must type in commandline